# Trouble getting Netbeans 7.4 working

Tags: c++, netbeans

Hi so thought I'd give c++ a try however I cant get the netbeans compiler working for a hello world..... so here is my code copy pasted from tutorial:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

and here is the error message im getting:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Jeremy/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello World'
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/hello\.d
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/hello/.d
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/hello_world.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Jeremy/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello World'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/hello world.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/hello world.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/hello\ world.o hello\ world.cpp
g++: error: world.o.d: No such file or directory
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:68: recipe for target 'build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/hello world.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/hello world.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Jeremy/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello World'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:60: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Jeremy/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello World'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 3s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you named your source file `hello world.cpp`. NetBeans doesn't seem to like this syntax.

The canonical way to name files is without spaces. `helloworld.cpp` would work better for you.